# Scheme function

Tags: function, scheme

I am trying to interpret what this scheme function does:

```
 (define (y s lis)
    (cond
      ((null? lis) '() )
      ((equal? s (car lis)) lis)
      (else (y s (cdr lis)))))
```

It runs but I am not exactly sure what it is doing or trying to do.
Does it need a list to sort or something? I am using DrRacket to run it. I have never seen scheme before
and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's strange that the part about DrRacket is on my edit in the history. Did you edit it out or should I add it again?

Comment: With the exception of returning `()` instead of `#f` when the searched item is not found, this function is identical to the standard `member` function. In other words, you can define this function thus: `(define (y s lis) (or (member s lis) '()))` ;-)

Comment: Add it again. I forgot to add it to my original post so I edited it in.

Comment: The answers to this homework problem are already given [here](http://www.core.binghamton.edu/~fortytwo/471assign8.html).  I found it by googling "y s lis".  It was the first hit.   Also, it appears that this is the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/q/20205171/1281433 (10k to see) which was asked by an account with the name Inquirer.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor if this is the same person, they acted wisely. :) By opening new accounts for each question they've found the workaround for the very possible and all too easily acquirable question ban which works on the IP level and is nearly impossible for newbies to overcome once in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a search function, that given a value and a list looks for the value in the list. If it finds it, returns the part of the list starting at the point where the element was found. If the value isn't in the list, it returns an empty list. Let's see how this works, step by step:

```
; define a function called `y` that receives
; as parameters a value `s` and a list `lis`
(define (y s lis)
  ; we're going to test three possible conditions
  (cond
    ; if the list is empty    
    ((null? lis)
     ; then we didn't find the value, return the empty list
     '())
    ; if the first element in the list equals the `s` value
    ((equal? s (car lis))
     ; then return the list up to this point
     lis)
    ; otherwise
    (else
     ; keep looking in the rest of the list, by recurring over it
     (y s (cdr lis)))))
```

To see the function in action, let's test it with some values:

```
; call the function with a value that is present in the list
(y 3 '(1 2 3 4 5))
; see how the list is returned starting at the point where the value was found
=> '(3 4 5)

; call the function with a value that is not present in the list
(y 7 '(1 2 3 4 5))
; an empty list is returned
=> '()
```

To really, really understand how this works, you have to realize that in the last line of the function we're calling the function itself - it's the magic of recursion! Also, it'll help you to understand what each one of the primitive operations used is doing, click on each link to read the documentation, I'm simplifying and summarizing the key points:

- [`define`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/define.html): give a name to a value (in particular, it can be a function)
- [`cond`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html?q=cond#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._cond%29%29): test for different conditions, execute some expressions depending on which condition was true
- [`null?`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=null%3F&q=cond#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._null~3f%29%29): test to see if a list is empty
- [`equal?`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/booleans.html?q=equal%3F&q=null%3F&q=cond#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._equal~3f%29%29): compare two objects for equality
- [`car`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=car&q=equal%3F&q=null%3F&q=cond#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._car%29%29): get the first element in a list
- [`cdr`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=cdr&q=car&q=equal%3F&q=null%3F&q=cond#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._cdr%29%29): get the rest of the elements in a list

Comment: That is very insightful Oscar. Thank you.

Comment: Oh alright. I'm new to stack over flow if you haven't noticed.

Comment: I tried voting your answer up but I guess I haven't earned that ability yet. lol

Answer (score 1):

We can go on a mystic journey and treat this definition as it is, a definition. Cryptic? This means equational reasoning, i.e. reasoning through equations, i.e. definitions. Here's what I mean. You have

```
(define (y s lis)
   (cond
      ((null? lis) '() )
      ((equal? s (car lis)) lis)
      (else (y s (cdr lis)))))
```

We can re-write this as two equations,

```
y s lis = lis             , if (null? lis) || (equal? s (car lis))
        = y s (cdr lis)   , otherwise
```

Here `y s lis` stands for *"the result of Scheme call `(y s lis)`"* and so on.

Clearly we have two cases. One is base case, another describes a *reduction* step. Re-writing again,

```
y s lis = y s (cdr lis)   , if (not (null? lis)) && (not (equal? s (car lis)))
        = lis             , otherwise
```

This is practically in English now. So while `lis` is not null, and its `car` isn't `s`, we proceed along to its `cdr`, and so on and so forth until either we hit the list's end, or its `car` is `s`, and then we stop. So when we've found `s`, we return the list, otherwise the list is exhausted and the empty list is returned. This is otherwise known as [`member`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mem_m.htm) in Common Lisp. [R5RS Scheme's `member`](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%_idx_432), as well as [Racket's](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#(def._((lib._racket/private/list..rkt)._member))), returns `#f` when no `x` is found in the list.

Where is the *equational* reasoning here, you ask? In treating the RHS as the answer, and re-applying the same set of rules for each reduction step. For example:

```
y x [a,b,x,c,d,e]                         ; A
    = y x [b,x,c,d,e]    ; by 1st rule    ; B
    = y x [x,c,d,e]      ; by 1st rule    ; C
    = [x,c,d,e]          ; by 2nd rule    ; D
```

When we get to apply the 2nd rule, we arrive at the end of the reduction chain, i.e. we get our answer. The result of the Scheme call corresponding to `A` will be the same as the Scheme call's corresponding to `B`, or `C`, or finally `D`:

```
(y x (cons a (cons b (cons x z)))) ==
(y x (cons b (cons x z))) ==
(y x (cons x z)) ==
(cons x z)
```

What's so *mystic* about it, you ask? Here probably not much; but usually what that means is that by assuming the meaning of a function, and by interpreting the RHS through it, we arrive at the meaning of the LHS; and if this is the same meaning, *that* is our proof for it. [*Induction*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_induction) is kind of magical. For more involved examples see [How to recursively reverse a list using only basic operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529829/how-to-recursively-reverse-a-list-using-only-basic-operations/19536834#19536834).

Incidentally structural recursion is also known as [*folding*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)), so your function is really

```
y s lis = para (λ (xs x r) (if (equal? x s) xs (r))) '() lis
```

using one type of folding, [*paramorphism*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paramorphism), with explicit laziness,

```
para f z lis = g lis 
  where 
     g xs = z                                  , if (null? xs)
          = f xs (car xs) (λ () (g (cdr xs)))  , otherwise
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its a test to see if element `s` is found inside the list `lst`.  I'm still learning Scheme (but I did get through The Little Schemer so let me try (this has likely been typed and submitted before I I finish this but I'll try anyways).

So define is creating a function called `y` that takes the arguments `s` and `lst`. The first line of this function is `cond` which goes though each list and tries to find some expression that evaluates to true. The first condition is the exit condition (always have an exit when you iterate) it checks to see if `lis` is null, if so it returns a quoted empty list (like the null of lists)

The next condition looks to see if the first element of `lst` (`car` takes the first element of a list) equals `s` if so then it returns the rest f the list  (this means it found the element).

The last condition is `else` which is alway true and it calls the function `y` with the same `s` and the list minus the first element (`cdr` returns a sublist of the list minus the first element). Hope this helps (and I hope I was right)

Here is an example of calling this function:

```
(y 'b (list 'a 'b 'c))
```

And this returns

```
('b 'c)
```

Comment: That seems to make sense. I just don't know enough to double check you. I will find something to read on it and get back to you. Thanks for the post.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like homework.

Since you are using DrRacket you should add

```
(y 'e '(q w e r t y))
```

And hit <kbd>Debug Q >|</kbd> and step through it. A different way to write the same code is:

```
(define (y s lis)
  (if (null? lis) 
      '()
      (if (equal? s (car lis)) 
          lis
          (y s (cdr lis)))))
```

Or you can choose `Intermediate student with lambda` from the language menu in the bottom left and then press <kbd>Step >|</kbd>.
That language doesn't support all of Scheme but a small subset, including everything in this procedure. It's great to see how things are evaluated.

Comment: Why do you suggest adding (y 'e '(q w e r t y))?

Comment: In order to test the procedure and either run debug or step you need to test it on something in the definitions window. That line calls procedure `y` with a literal `e` and a literal list `(q w e r t y)` as arguments. Evaluating the `define` form alone only creates a binding to `y` but does not do anything with it.

Comment: @Inquirer21 I suggest you play a little with the arguments to see what happens. `equal?` can compare things that look a like. Eg. `(y '(test) '((this) (is) (a) (test) (with) (lists)))`.

Comment: @Sylwester It does seem to be homework;  there's an answer [here](http://www.core.binghamton.edu/~fortytwo/471assign8.html).