# defining map in terms of reduce

Tags: scheme, higher-order-functions

I have just picked up John Hughes' essay [Why Functional Programming Matters](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~rjmh/Papers/whyfp.pdf), and i'm trying to follow along using Scheme.

The first higher order function he defines is reduce, which i've defined in Scheme as follows:

```
(define u-reduce
  (lambda (ff init lst)
    (if (null? lst)
      init
      (ff (car lst) (u-reduce ff init (cdr lst))))))
```

I can re-create some of the applications of `reduce` in the essay using this function, however things break apart in the move from `reduce` to `map`.

The motivating example is `doubleall = reduce doubleandcons nil`, where `doubleandcons num list = cons (2*num) list`.

I am not sure how to translate this into scheme. I can see that the target result can be made with:

```
(define doubleandcons
  (lambda (lst)
    (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (cons (* 2 (car lst)) (doubleandcons (cdr lst))))))

(doubleandcons '(1 2 3))
> (2 4 6)
```

However can not see what to pass to `reduce` to get it to double each element of a list - perhaps because i keep jumping to a version of `map` (see `u-map` below) as the solution to the problem.

I can see that `init` = `'()`, but not what function to pass in to the `ff` place to make `u-reduce` behave like `u-map`.

```
(define u-map
  (lambda (ff lst)
    (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (cons (ff (car lst)) (u-map ff (cdr lst))))))

(u-map (lambda (x) (* 2 x)) '(1 2 3))
> (2 4 6)
```

Is this possible? Or perhaps i'm missing the point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(define u-map
  (lambda (ff lst)
    (reduce (lambda (x y) (cons (ff x) y)) '() lst)))
```

Folding cons across a list gives you a copy of that list.

Comment: +1 / accepted: `(u-reduce (lambda (x y) (cons ((lambda (x) (* 2 x)) x) y)) '() '(1 2 3))` was exactly the bridge i needed.

Answer (score 3):

Common Lisp `reduce` is a general `fold`. In Scheme you have `fold-right` that does elements in order. Your `u-reduce` works just like a right fold with it's arguments in the same order. Thus the following should work in R6RS/R7RS:

```
(define (my-map fun lst)
  (fold-right (lambda (x a) (cons (fun x) a)) '() lst))
```

As you can see I'm using the passed function in an anonymous function to `fold-right` to do the `cons` as well.

In other versions of Scheme and Racket you get the same behavior by using [SRFI-1: List library](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#fold-right), Many implementation has support for it so look in it's documentation how you import/require it.

Answer (score 2):

You should define your `reduce` as explicitly lazy, since the article is all about the importance and utility of *laziness*.

The usual `reduce` is a (right) fold, i.e. a catamorphism (cf. Haskell's `foldr`), but let's define a [paramorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317242/what-are-paramorphisms/13317563#13317563) for generality:

```
(define (para f z lst)
   (if (null? lst)
      z
      (f lst (car lst)      ;; usually, f (cdr lst) (car lst) ...
         (lambda () (para f z (cdr lst))))))
```

(see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20304591/849891)). We use it like this:

```
;; doubleall = reduce doubleandcons nil
;;   where  doubleandcons num rest = cons (2*num) rest

(define (doubleall lst) 
   (para doubleandcons '() lst))

(define (doubleandcons lst num rest)   ; ignore input lst
   (cons (* 2 num) (rest)))            ; force the lazy rest

(define (member elt lst)
   (para (lambda (xs x r) 
            (if (equal? x elt) xs (r)))  ; conditionally force, or
         '() lst))                       ;  ignore the rest

(define (mymap f lst)
   (para 
      (lambda (xs x r) 
         (cons (f x) (r)))    ; cons the result of calling f w/ x,
      '() lst))               ;   onto the rest

(define (all pred lst)
   (para
      (lambda (xs x r) 
         (and (pred x) (r)))  ; possibly short-circuit
      #t lst))
```

You cannot short-circuit with your version because it evaluates the rest *before* passing it as an argument to the combining function (`ff`).

Comment: your function `para` looks a little like _CPS_, but the lambda is that's passed isn't a function of anything - why is this? I plan on following your links, but an explanation of how this makes the function _explicitly lazy_ would be helpful.

Comment: simply by encasing the expression inside a *lambda*, creates a function that *will* perform its action, *when* called. This is known as *delaying* the execution (of a piece of code). Under lazy evaluation model this happens automatically - *everything* gets delayed. Here we do it explicitly, for a certain part of a computation. So no, that's not CPS because the lambda has no arguments. Such lambdas are known as *"thunks"* BTW.

Comment: I don't understand the need to pass `lst` in the recursive step. I can re-write all of your example functions and re-write `para` without it in the recursive step `(f (car lst) (lambda () ...))` without it, and nothing seems to break.

Comment: exactly right! (almost) :) -- `lst` is a part of "protocol" of paramorphism; without it, it'd be a catamorphism, i.e. a traditional fold; except that *`member` needs `lst`*, it can't be defined so easily with catamorphism (it can, but just not so easily and straightforwardly). that's why I said "for generality". :) but mostly it's unused. :)

Comment: ... and it's not "in the recursive step", on the contrary, it's in the re-combination step. :)

Comment: are there practical cases where it's an important distinction? i haven't read widely on the subject just yet, but it seems mostly of theoretical interest (to do with the links to category theory).  Is a _paramorphism_ a more general class of `fold` than a _catamorphism_?

Comment: between cata and para, you mean? but I am showing the practical difference there, in the impl of `member`. :) With catamorphism, we'd have to wriggle it into `(define (member elt lst) (cata (lambda (xs r) (if (equal? (car xs) elt) xs (r))) '() (maplist (lambda (x) x) lst)))`, with [`maplist` as in Common Lisp](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm), `(define (maplist f lst) (if (null? lst) '() (cons (f lst) (maplist f (cdr lst)))))`.

Comment: User "pigworker" wrote in an answer here on SO about general technique of simulating para with cata by recreating the (copy of) the original list, which is even more cumbersome. Para does give more info to the combining function, so does it mean it's more "general"? Perhaps. It's just two different tools.

Comment: my eyes are just starting to open -- can you recommend introductory materials? Also, most of what i can find uses haskell: is haskell the lingua franca of this community?

Comment: Haskell has much more visual syntax, much less noise, to me, though YMMV. I was interested in Prolog and Scheme first. Haskell is pretty much unavoidable. :) Before you get into their "monads" stuff, be sure to read http://squing.blogspot.com/2008/01/unmonad-tutorial-io-in-haskell-for-non.html. It talks about IO but is applicable for any monad. Practically, "monadic" code is just programs in some DSL, each type of monad defining their own DSL with its special functions - in addition to "how to perform one command after another". e.g. with or w/out exceptions, w/ or w/out error messages, etc.

Comment: usually recommended are "LYAH haskell" (search) and "RWH haskell" and haskell.org. You're already reading WFPM. :) But, there's no such good documentation as there's for Racket. -- Also, there's Friedman and Wise's TR44 and TR19, and Steel and Sussman's "lambda" papers - the foundational stuff, IMHO. (predates Haskell per se). Haskell is more or less just lazy Scheme with syntax and types (and type inference). It's all related. :)