# SICP Exercise 2.33 issue

Tags: lambda, scheme, lisp, sicp

having a bit of a problem with this exercise.  specifically, 'seeing' how the lambda expression works

the exercise itself says this..

```
(define (map p sequence)
(accumulate (lambda (x y) <??>) nil sequence))
```

has to turn into this...

```
(define (map p sequence)
   (accumulate (lambda (x y) (cons (p x) y)) null sequence))
```

but i don't understand.  i mean, i see that the 'accumulate' procedure follows the (define (accumulate op initial sequence)... form

so, does this mean (lambda (x y) (cons (p x) y)) is the 'op' part?  & if so, what are x & y & how are they passed into the equation?

(decent explanation much appreciated)

Comment: [you have the power](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) to [up-vote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) now. :)

Answer (score 2):

First, let's take a look at `accumulate` as defined in the book:

```
(define (accumulate op initial sequence)
  (if (null? sequence)
      initial
      (op (car sequence)
          (accumulate op initial (cdr sequence)))))
```

Basically, it's an ad-hoc implementation of [`foldr`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldr%29%29) (a.k.a. `fold-right`), a higher-order procedure that processes an input list, applying a certain *operation* on each element and accumulating the result.

Notice that the `op` parameter is a procedure that looks like this (let's rename `x` and `y` to something more meaningful):

```
(lambda (element accumulator) <body>)
```

In the above, `element` represents the current element in the input list, each one of the elements is processed in turn in left-to-right order, and `accumulator` is the accumulated value of the output, which is being built recursively as we traverse the list. The `<body>` part takes care of updating the accumulated value, by doing something with the current element and the accumulated value. Now, let's take a look at how we usually write `map`:

```
(define (map p sequence)
  (if (null? sequence)
      null
      (cons (p (car sequence))
            (map p (cdr sequence)))))
```

Do you notice the pattern? `map` is very, very similar to `accumulate`, we just have to:

1. Pass an appropriate `initial` value: `null` will be perfect
2. Provide an `op` procedure that applies `p` to the current element in the list and `cons`es it to the result of the recursive call

And that's exactly what we do, when we call `accumulate` with just the right parameters:

```
(define (map p sequence)
  (accumulate (lambda (element accumulator)
                (cons (p element) accumulator))
              null
              sequence))
```

The key insight to notice is that this line in the `lambda` body:

```
(cons (p element) accumulator)
```

Is doing *exactly* the same as this other line in the original `map`:

```
(cons             (p (car sequence))            (map p (cdr sequence)))
 ^^^^             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 cons both parts  apply `p` on current element  all this is the accumulated value
```

To see why, use the substitution model and replace `op`, `initial` and `sequence` (the parameters in `accumulate`) with the actual values that we passed as arguments.

Comment: cheers dude.  can't see it yet but thanks for the help.  am working on it

Answer (score 1):

> so, does this mean (lambda (x y) (cons (p x) y)) is the 'op' part?

yes.

> & if so, what are x & y & how are they passed into the equation?

`x` is *"the current element"* and `y` is *"the result of recursively calling `(accumulate ...)` on the rest of the list"*.

Here's what this means. Each given list is seen as a cons pair - a pair of its `car` and its `cdr`. The value of a list's `car` goes into `x`, and of `cdr` - to the recursive call whose result goes into `y`. Or in equational style,

```
accumulate( op, z, CONS(e,es) ) = op( e, accumulate(op, z, es) )
```

where `CONS(e,es)` is not a function call, but a data representation (using the upper case to signify this) - a *cons cell* with `e` in its `car` and `es` (read: *eez*, like in *e, plural*) in its `cdr`. So when `op(x,y) = ...` is called, `x = e` and `y = accumulate(op, z, es)` are passed into it.

The above equation defines the function `accumulate`. One more equation is needed, for the `NIL` [case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_induction):

```
accumulate( op, z, NIL ) = z
```

Thus it is assumed that `op` is a binary operation (i.e. receiving two arguments), able to deal with results of `accumulate` as its second argument. This pattern of list processing is known as ["folding"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29), or "catamorphism" - i.e. processing the data *down*, analyzing the data into its constituent parts, and recombining them in a certain fashion, arranging for a certain "call protocol" for the binary operation.

There are other patterns as well, e.g. a so-called "paramorphism",

```
accumulate2( op, z, NIL ) = z
accumulate2( op, z, CONS(e,es) ) = op( e, es, accumulate2(op, z, es) )
```

Here the operation is assumed to be ternary (i.e. receiving three arguments), receiving the current element, the rest of input list, and the result of recursive processing of the rest of the input list. It is useful in implementing patterns of data processing which need to have access to input as well as output (what's sometimes referred to, cryptically, as "having your cake and eating it too").

To be more useful these definitions need to be encoded [lazily](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation), so `op` has a choice of whether to force the recursive result or not, to be able to abort early (see e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21876663/defining-map-in-terms-of-reduce/21891709#21891709)).

Comment: cheers.  as i said to the dude above, the penny hasn't properly dropped yet (but i'm keeping at it so hopefully it will do eventually)

Comment: @user3435279 was my answer helpful at all? I thought the equational definitions should be clear enough. If *recursion* is your difficulty, try http://stackoverflow.com/a/19951540/849891 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/11666815/849891. It might seem mysterious at first, the ability to call itself, but the key is that it's not "self" that gets called - but rather a ***copy*** of self.

Comment: no it is dude, v helpful.  at least today.  yesterday brain wasn't so receptive but this recursion thing & SICP are hard (probably hardest thing i've ever studied & i've studied lots of stuff)

Comment: @user3435279 you know this joke, about how to boil some eggs? you need a pot, a stove, a water faucet and matches, and then you have a procedure how to boil yourself some eggs in a pot full of water by placing it on a stove and lighting it with a match, right? And what if you're already given a pot full of water with eggs in it, and a stove is already lit? How do you boil eggs then, in the spirit of *code reuse* / *structural recursion* ?

Comment: @user3435279 OK, here it is: you take the eggs out, pour out the water, turn off the stove, and are left with the situation you already know how to handle! :) IOW, don't try to see the big picture; work in-the-small. Which is the attitude of structural recursion: `(define (boil-some-eggs situation) (cond ((basic-situation? situation) (pour-water-in-put-eggs-in-turn-the-stove-on! situation)) (else (let ((basic-situation (analyze-into-constituent-parts situation))) (boil-some-eggs basic-situation)))))`.

Comment: consider the terseness of this question, its amazing (a) how different your & mr lopez's explanations of the answers are, & (b) how much study time i've been able to sink into it (~ 3 days) without properly feeling like i've cracked it.  [ i think i'm about 85% there currently ]

Comment: @user3435279 what is still unclear? I don't see much difference BTW. :) He mentions `foldr` too (cf. my reference to "folding"). Did you like the joke at least?

Comment: lol.  lots.  not so much the joke itself but at your question of whether i like it.   i mean, maybe when i've finished SICP & thinking recursively comes as easily as blowing bubbles... perhaps then i'll be able to process it as-a-joke.  for now, like 99.9999% of people, its an exam question

Comment: Ah, the joke should've been: given eggs in a water in a pot and a burning stove, we'd just place the pot on the fire. ***But what would a programmer do?*** -- he'd take everything out because "that's the ***basic case*** we already know how to deal with". Funny. But actually this near-sighted attitude guarantees to him that he deals with the situation correctly (makes no errors trying to be smart about it). -- The counter-joke is about a centipede who gets asked, "how exactly *do* you walk with your 100 legs?" after which he becomes motionless, thinking which leg to move first.

Comment: @user3435279 (see also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19951540/849891, near the end of that post).

Answer (score 0):

What helped me a lot in some of the exercises in this section of SICP was to introduce some `print` statements for seeing what is happening in the calls of `accumulate` or other functions which are called recursively.

Like that: (I am using [Racket](http://racket-lang.org/) so I am not sure if the `printf` is also defined in other Schemes)

```
(define (accumulate op initial seq)
  (printf "op: ~a, initial: ~a, seq: ~a\n" op initial seq)
  (if (null? seq)
      initial
      (op (car seq)
          (accumulate op initial (cdr seq)))))
```