# Reverse a list with dolist in LISP

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I try to reverse a list, i can't use the function "nreverse"

I try  :

```
(defun dolist-reverse (l)
  (let ((new-list (make-list (length l))))
    (dolist (x l new-list)
      (setf new-list (cons x new-list)))))
```

But the result is :

> CL-USER> (dolist-reverse '(1 2 3))
>
> (3 2 1 NIL NIL NIL)

How can i do ? (i need to use dolist)

**EDIT :**

Finally fix my problem :

```
(defun dolist-reverse (l)
  (let ((new-list))
    (dolist (x l new-list)
      (setf new-list (cons x new-list)))))
```

Comment: If you found a solution to your problem, then you should post it as an answer with an explanation and mark it accepted.

Answer (score 3):

```
CL-USER 11 > (defun dolist-reverse (list &aux (reverse-list nil))
               (dolist (element list reverse-list)
                 (push element reverse-list)))
DOLIST-REVERSE

CL-USER 12 > (dolist-reverse '(1 2 3))
(3 2 1)
```

Answer (score -1):

This one makes same thing, without changing argument to the procedure;

```
 (defun my-reverse (l)
     (if (null l) nil
       (append
         (my-reverse (cdr l))
         (list (car l)))))
```

Comment: martialp, why do you need dolist?

Comment: why append is a very bad idea?

Comment: and the reason i did the above to both to show existence of an algorithm without iterative constructs, and the simplicity of the idea behind expressing reverse of a list as being reverse of rest of the list glued to first of the list.

Comment: @user97457 good; :) more than that, you can do it without `append` too, only `cons`. [Here's a link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19529829/849891) -  or try solve it first by yourself.. -- repeated append at the end is bad because it copies its first argument. your algorithm is quadratic (at least). So it's only a fun toy. :)