# How to reverse the order of elements of a list in Scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I got a function to reverse the order of the elements in a list, such as

```
(define (rvsl sequence)
  (foldl (lambda (x y) 
           (cons y x)) 
         '() sequence))
```

However, when I ran it in DrRacket with the input

```
(rvsl (list 2 3 4))
```

DrRacket told me this

```
cons: second argument must be a list, but received empty and 2
```

Could anybody please give me some ideas to solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just use `(cons x y)` instead of `(cons y x)`.

Comment: You defined rvsl to take two arguments and only passed it one when you used it. You can either pass it two arguments from the start, or create another procedure which will pass the proper number of arguments to rvsl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you're passing the parameters in the wrong order - when using `cons` to build a list, the first parameter is the new element we want to stick at the beginning of the list, and the second one is the list we've built so far.

Having said that, reversing a list using `foldl` is a bit simpler and you don't need to use `append` at all - in fact, it's a bad practice using `append` when `cons` suffices:

```
(define (rvsl sequence)
  (foldl cons
         '()
         sequence))
```

Why this works? let's rewrite the function being more explicit this time:

```
(define (rvsl sequence)
  (foldl (lambda (current accumulated)
           (cons current accumulated))
         '()
         sequence))
```

Now we can see that the `lambda` procedure receives two parameters: the `current` element in the input list, and the `accumulated` value so far - good parameter names make all the difference in the world! this is much, much clearer than calling the parameters `x` and `y`, which says nothing about them.

In this case, we just want to `cons` the current element at the head of the accumulated value (which starts as an empty list), hence producing a reversed list as the output. Given that the `lambda` procedure receives two parameters and passes them in the same order to `cons`, we can simplify the whole thing and just pass the `cons` procedure as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You don't *have* to use `foldl` or anything else, actually, to define the `rev` function; the `rev` function itself is enough:

```lisp
(define (rev ls)                                 ; rev [] = []
  (cond                                          ; rev [x] = [x]
    ((null? ls) ls)                              ; rev (x:xs) 
    ((null? (rest ls)) ls)                       ;   | (a:b) <- rev xs 
    (else                                        ;   = a : rev (x : rev b)
      (cons (first (rev (rest ls)))
            (rev (cons (first ls)
                       (rev (rest (rev (rest ls))))))))))
```

(comments in equational pattern-matching pseudocode). Derivation and some discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19536834/849891).

(*edit:* that's obviously a toy code, just to hone your Scheme-fu).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple version, using an internal iterative procedure.

```
(define (rev lst)
  (define (iter accum lst)
    (if (null? lst)
        accum
        (iter (cons (car lst) accum)
              (cdr lst))))
  (iter '() lst))
```