# Scheme lisp cons and list

Tags: scheme

I tried reversing a list in scheme using the most basic concept I had about cons,cdr,car.
Here,`l-orig` is the list to be reversed and `l-count` acts as a counter.

My code goes here:

```
(define (rev l-orig l-count)
(
    if (null? l-count)
    (cons l-orig '())
    (rev (cons (cdr l-orig) (car l-orig)) (cdr l-count))
)
)
(display (rev '(1 2 3 4 5) '(1 1 1 1 1)))
```

And the output is `(((2 3 4 5) . 1))`
Honestly speaking, I am a beginner in lisp and I need a simple help here.
If I intend to use this method, can anyone suggest me a correct way of doing it?

Comment: related?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529829/how-to-recursively-reverse-a-list-using-only-basic-operations/19536834#19536834

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to reverse a list using tail recursion, with the help of an accumulator parameter. The best way would be to traverse the original list and `cons` each of its elements at the head of the accumulator, which will be returned at the end:

```
(define (rev l-orig l-count)
  (if (null? l-orig)
      l-count
      (rev (cdr l-orig) (cons (car l-orig) l-count))))
```

Notice that the accumulator starts as an empty list, which is perfect for `cons`ing each new element to it:

```
(rev '(1 2 3 4 5) '())
=> '(5 4 3 2 1)
```

Comment: This solution is readily acceptable. But my objective is to get the reversed list in l-orig itself. I just want to use l-count as a counter. Any help on this?

Comment: Don't. In Scheme, we try to avoid modifying the input, instead we prefer to build a new output, that's the functional programming way.

Answer (score 0):

Oscar's answer is right on. You can use a helper function so you don't need to pass in an empty accumulator every time:

```
(define (rev xs)
  (rev-accum xs '()))

(define (rev-accum xs accum)
  (if (null? xs)
      accum
      (rev-accum (cdr xs) (cons (car xs) accum))))
```