# Reversing a list in Scheme with restrictions

Tags: list, scheme, racket, reverse, restriction

I already have the code to reverse a list:

```
    (define (myreverse lst)
       (if (null? lst)
          lst
          (append (reverse (cdr lst))
                  (list (car lst)))))
```

But I want to do this using only `lectrec`, `cons`, `car` and `cdr`. How can I do that?

Comment: You [don't even need `letrec`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19536834/849891) (besides the one which `define` itself encodes, in effect).

Comment: Only those, not including `if`, `null?`, or `append`?

Comment: @AlexKnauth not `append` I imagine, but you're right, the other two can't be avoided.

Comment: There is a bug in your initial code. Should use `myreverse` and not `reverse`. How it is now you only add the the first elemenet last and use a different procedure to do the rest of the list reversal.

Comment: Using only named procedures is completely impossible.

Comment: @Sylwester cons car cdr null? and cond is enough, so must be with if instead of cond too. (see the link in my topmost comment)

Comment: @WillNess but you don't have `cond`, `define` or `null?`. OP wants a solution using only  `lectrec`, `cons`, `car` and `cdr` and then you have no way to do a base case.

Comment: @Sylwester if that's what you meant then of course. if and null? are a must. I should expect define be acceptable in place of letrec, which, if not, is unusable without lambda.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to reverse a list without append is to use the helper function REVAPPEND, like this:

```
(define (reverse x) (revappend x '()))
(define (revappend x y)
  (if (null? x)
      y
      (revappend (cdr x) (cons (car x) y))))
```

Now if you want to implement reverse as a single function you can use LETREC to locally define the REVAPPEND helper, like this

```
(define (reverse x)
  (let revappend ((x x) (y '()))
    ...))
```

This is just a template to get you started, feel free to ask if you need more help.