# How to Write a Reverse Function in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket, computer-science

I have to write a scheme function which does the following:

Define a SCHEME function, named `(rev p)`, which takes a pair as an argument and evaluates to
another pair with the first and second elements in the pair p in reverse order. For instance,

```
( rev ( cons 1 2))
> (2 . 1)
```

Here is my code:

```
(define (rev p)
  (cond ((null? p) '())
        (not (pair? (car p)) p)
        (else (append (rev (cdr p)) (list (rev (car p))))
```

However, my code returns `(1 . 2)` when I test it when it should be returning `(2 . 1)`.

Comment: From the description you provided it seems like you are only dealing with pairs and not with lists.

Comment: So `(rev '(1 2 3)) ; ==> ((2 3) . 1)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just a *pair* that you want to reverse, it's pretty simple, you don't even need to do recursion! And remember to use `cons`, not `append`:

```
(define (rev p)
  (cond ((not (pair? p)) p)
        (else (cons (cdr p) (car p)))))
```

For example:

```
(rev '())
=> '()
(rev 5)
=> 5
(rev (cons 1 2))
=> '(2 . 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(define rev
  (lambda (l acc)
    (if (null? l)
        acc
        (rev (cdr l)(cons (car l) acc)))))

(rev '(1 2 3) '())
```

And here is an apparently obfuscate version, but the ideas may be useful.

```
(define rev
  (lambda (l k)
    (if (null? l)
        (k (lambda (x) x))
        (rev (cdr l)
             (lambda (k0)
               (k (lambda (r) (k0 (cons (car l) r)))))))))

((rev '(1 2 3) (lambda (x) x)) '())
```

--

As suggested by Will, here is other variant, non-tail recursive, hence not completely cps'd, it's a combination of classic recursion and cps.

```
(define rev
  (lambda (l k)
    (if (null? l)
        (k '())
        (rev (cdr l)
             (lambda (r)
               (cons (car l)
                     (k r)))))))
```

Comment: here's [some quite crazy way to reverse a list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19536834/849891), for your perusal. :) re your code, it *is* quite complicated, I could only make sense of it after doing [some sample reductions](https://pastebin.com/YQgTtRBd). there's a simpler way to do it with CPS, too.

Comment: @WillNess completed your variant, too.

Comment: you're right, I thought about it also, that it is not really CPS, it just builds the lambda function to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Or the same expressed as:

```
(define (rev p)
  (if (pair? p)
      (cons (cdr p) (car p))
      p))
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do for this function is use the car and cdr function for your pair p.

```
(define (rev p)
    (cons (cdr p) (car p))
    )
```