# Reversing a list in Scheme with some restrictions

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, scheme, racket, whitelist

I'm trying to reverse a list in Scheme, but I can only use **define**, **car**, **cdr**, **list?**, **null?**, **if**, **cond**, **cons**, **display**, **begin**,  and any operators. I cannot use append, loops (must be pure recursion), lambda and any other functions that I have not mentioned. I'm also not allowed to use helper functions. Everything should be in one function.

It's been hours now and I've tried multiple solutions and I still cannot solve this. This is the closest solution that I got:

```
(define (my-reverse2 lis)
    (if (null? (cdr lis)) lis
        (cons (my-reverse2 (cdr lis)) (cons (car lis) '()))))
```

And this is the output:

```
> (my-reverse2 '(3 2 1))
Output: (list (list (list 1) 2) 3)
```

The output should be something like `(1 2 3)`. How should I proceed?

Comment: When creating a list you do the elements in opposite order and when you iterate you do them in order. Reversing is just recursing the CDR while consing the CAR element to an accumulator initialized as the empty list. When your base case hits you evaluate that accumulator since it will have the reversed list.

Comment: the first `cons` in your `my-reverse2` must be changed to `append` to make it work, but you said `append` isn't allowed. the `'()` which you use doesn't appear in your list of allowed symbols either.

Comment: @Sylwester the empty list doesn't appear in the list of allowed entities.

Comment: @WillNess What does `null?` do except checking if the argument is the empty list? Also where does it limit literals in the solution?

Comment: "and any operators”. What is an operator? According to SICP it is the first element in an application. Eg in  `(bla ble bli)` `bla` is an operator while `ble` and `bli` are operands. If I can use any operator wony that remove the restriction on valid forms?

Comment: @Sylwester the whitelist in the post includes `null?` but does not include `'()`, is all I'm saying.  Indeed the literal `'()` is not used in my solution.

Comment: @WillNess use of `'()` may be implied as it is used in the OP's attempt?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use an accumulator value:

```
(define (my-reverse the-list acc)
  (if (null? the-list)
      acc
      (my-reverse (cdr the-list)
                  (cons (car the-list) acc))))
```

You call this `(my-reverse '(1 2 3) '())`. If there were optional arguments in Scheme you could make the `acc` optional with a default value of the empty list. In my code I would usually have a wrapper around this with a single argument only which then calls the two argument version with the empty list.

Comment: `'()` isn't listed as an allowed entity. :)

Answer (score 1):

First, reverse the `cdr` and take its `car` -- which will be ... the *last* element, right? -- and its `cdr` will be the reversed *core*, i.e. the original list without its last and first element.

Then, `cons` the original `car` onto the reversed core, *reversed*, thus getting all the elements of the list without the last one, in original order. So then now we can reverse *that*, and `cons` the last element onto the result.

Simple, right? Yeah, not so much. So here's an illustration:

```
a b c ...... m n                                         ; car, cdr:
  b c ...... m n                                         ; reversen-1:
|              n m ...... c b                            ; car, cdr:
|                m ...... c b                            ; reversen-2:
|              |            b c ...... m                 ; cons a:
a              |            b c ...... m                 ; reversen-1:
               |                       m ...... c b a    ; cons n:
               n                       m ...... c b a    ; =: reversen
```

All this needs is `cdr`, `car`, `cons`, `null?`, `cond`, and recursion.  `let`/`define` will help a lot but is not strictly necessary. Do not forget to take care of the corner cases.

See also: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19536834/849891) related answer of mine.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most inefficient `reverse` ever written but it does meet the criteria in your question. By the end of this exercise you should be fairly comfortable thinking purely in terms of `car` and `cdr` -

```scm
(define (reverse t)
  (if (null? t)
      t
      (if (null? (cdr t))
          t
          (cons (car (reverse (cdr t)))
                (reverse
                 (cons (car t) 
                       (reverse
                        (cdr (reverse (cdr t))))))))))
```

```scm
(reverse '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9))
```

```scm
'(9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1)
```

Well dangit, this is basically what @WillNess wrote :D

If `let` is allowed, you can remove two instances of `(reverse (cdr t))` -

```scm
(define (reverse t)
  (if (null? t)
      t
      (if (null? (cdr t))
          t
          (let ((q (reverse (cdr t))))
            (cons (car q)
                  (reverse (cons (car t)
                                 (reverse (cdr q)))))))))
```

If `or` is allowed, we can collapse the two `if` -

```scm
(define (reverse t)
  (if (or (null? t) (null? (cdr t)))
      t
      (let ((q (reverse (cdr t))))
        (cons (car q)
              (reverse (cons (car t)
                             (reverse (cdr q))))))))
```

Comment: @WillNess, of course now i'm torturing myself trying to solve the problem using delimited continuations... let me know if you see a solution :D

Comment: will read later when I have time... :) not for several hours for sure. :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to use optional arguments?

```
(define (my-reverse lst [lst2 '()])
  (if (null? lst) lst2
      (my-reverse (cdr lst)
                  (cons (car lst) lst2))))
```

Test:

```
> (my-reverse '(3 2 1))
'(1 2 3)
```

Comment: `lst2` is a bad name for an accumulator / result 

Comment: Great minds think alike :)

Comment: `'()` isn't listed as an allowed entity.